# SQL script - update table based on excel data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables:

Product: IDProduct, ProductPartNumber

Manual: IDManual

ProductManual: IDProduct, IDManual

I have to update the link between product and manual based on a list of data(with 2-3000 entries) that contains the following two columns: ProductPartNumber, NewProductPartNumber.

What I want to accomplish is go through the ProductManual table and where the IDProduct corresponds to a ProductPartNumber from the list of data, replace it with the IDProduct corresponding to the NewProductPartNumber.

How can I do this? I thought I'd do it in a transaction that would roll back in case something unexpected happens because this script will alter the production database.

Comment: I thing, I can help you, but question is incomprehensible at all for me ), if you provide more info it'll be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way1: With sql batch you can create a temp table for your list of data and run the sql below:

BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE #TempProductPartNumber(ProductPartNumber INT, NewProductPartNumber INT)
-- insert your list of data into this temp table

UPDATE Product
SET Product.ProductPartNumber = #TempProductPartNumber.NewProductPartNumber
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN ProductManual ON Product.IDProduct = ProductManual.IDProduct
INNER JOIN #TempProductPartNumber ON #TempProductPartNumber.ProductPartNumber = Product.ProductPartNumber

COMMIT TRAN

Way2: Get all the data of Product  and ProductManual , update the data with linq in the same way and update the data back to DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a formula in excel to create an update script for each row:

```
="UPDATE Product p SET p.ProductPartNumber = " & A2 & " WHERE p.ProductPartNumber = " & A1
```

and then

```
="UPDATE ProductManual m SET m.IDProduct= " & A2 & " WHERE m.IDProduct= " & A1
```

and then run all rows